# CAAnimation: Syncing view's alpha with presentation layer's opacity

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm animating the `opacity` of a view's layer using `CAKeyframeAnimation`, when app goes to background, the animation's removed, but I need to make the view's alpha to be the same as the animation, should I do:

```
view.alpha = view.layer.presentationLayer.opacity
```

???

Thanks!

Update:

I have three labels overlapping with each other, I used key frame animation to animate their `opacity` with different key frame values (for `opacity`) to mimic a crossfade animation. The problem is when app goes to background, the animations are removed (according to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15796) so they all have alpha 1 and overlap with each other, that's why I wanted to sync the view with their presentation layer.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what your animation is, but you might consider using a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, in which case you can `pauseAnimation`  when the app leaves foreground and `startAnimation` to resume it when it re-enters foreground. But it's hard to get more specific without knowing what precisely your animation is.

Comment: @Rob Hi thanks, I'll give it a try. I updated my question with details about the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to capture the `opacity` when the app goes in background, you can add an observer for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground`, capture the opacity, cancel the animation, and set the `alpha`. E.g., in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewToAnimate: UIView!

    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
            if let opacity = self?.viewToAnimate.layer.presentation()?.opacity {
                self?.viewToAnimate.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                self?.viewToAnimate.alpha = CGFloat(opacity)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    // I'm just doing a basic animation, but the idea is the same whatever animation you're doing

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
            self.viewToAnimate.alpha = 0
        }
    }

}
```

If your goal is to remember it even if the app is terminated, then you'd need to save this in persistent storage. But if your goal is to merely set the `alpha` while the app is suspended and/or running in background, the above is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tick your answer. Actually the animation's removed automatically when app goes to background, see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15796, I didn't know this and saw some weird behaviour when switching apps, after seeing the answer in the link I re-add the animation when app comes to foreground. I have three labels overlapping each other and I animate their `opacity` at with different key frame values to mimic a cross fade effect, however when the animations are removed, they all have alpha 1 so that they overlay with each other.

Comment: I’m not stopping the animation because I didn’t think they’d stop when the app went into background, but rather just because I wanted it to stop before I set the alpha. It’s a very common pattern: grab presentation layer values, stop animation, reset view properties.